# App Engine social platform - Content interactions modeling strategy

Tags: python, google-app-engine, social-networking

I have a Python server running on Google app engine and implements a social network. I am trying to find the best way (best=fast and cheap) to implement interactions on items.
Just like any other social network I have the stream items ("Content") and users can "like" these items.

As for queries, I want to be able to:

1. Get the list of users who liked the content
2. Get a total count of the likers.
3. Get an intersection of the likers with any other users list.

My Current implementation includes:
1. IntegerProperty on the content item which holds the total likers count
2. InteractionModel - a NdbModel with a key id qual to the content id (fast fetch) and a JsonPropery the holds the likers usernames

Each time a user likes a content I need to update the counter and the list of users. This requires me to run and pay for 4 datastore operations (2 reads, 2 writes).
On top of that, items with lots of likers results in an InteractionModel with a huge json that takes time to serialize and deserialize when reading/writing (Still faster then RepeatedProperty).
None of the updated fields are indexed (built-in index) nor included in combined index (index.yaml)

Looking for a more efficient and cost effective way to  implement the same requirements.

Answer (score 1):

I´m guessing you have two entities in you model: User and Content. Your queries seem to aggregate upon multiple Content objects.

What about keeping this aggregated values on the User object? This way, you don´t need to do any queries, but rather only look up the data stored in the User object for these queries.

At some point though, you might consider not using the datastore, but look at sql storage instead. It has a higher constant cost, but I´m guessing at some point (more content/users) it might be worth considering both in terms of cost and performance.